# Ubuntu cannot open shared library mysqlx.so

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7, plugins

#### MySQL Server version:

```
Ubuntu: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log (Ubuntu)
```

MySQL installed using `apt-get`.

When installing a plugin with the following command:

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.so';
```

...I receive the following error message:

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

What can't Ubuntu locate/find the `mysqlx.so` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** By default `ubuntu-18.04` `apt-get` package does not include `mysqlx.so` plugin file, but `macOS` `mysql-server` installation contains `mysqlx.so` by default.

> How to enable `mysqlx.so`?

Run the following command in `mysql>` console to know whether `mysqlx.so` is installed or not:

```
mysql> SHOW PLUGINS\G
```

By default, 'mysqlx' will not present in the list. To enable it execute the following (for more info [click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html)),

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.so';
```

```
Output:
...
*************************** 45. row ***************************
   Name: mysqlx
 Status: ACTIVE
   Type: DAEMON
Library: mysqlx.so
License: GPL
...
```

In my case it is **not** listed in the output. (Now read the initial problem posted my me)

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/mysqlx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)

My Solution is hard path: Build `mysql-server-5.7` from the source (providing all the dependencies)

After the [Post installation Setup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/postinstallation.html) for `mysql-server`, execute the following commands in `mysql>` console:

```
mysql> INSTALL PLUGIN mysqlx SONAME 'mysqlx.so';
mysql> SHOW PLUGINS\G
```

```
Output:
...
*************************** 45. row ***************************
   Name: mysqlx
 Status: ACTIVE
   Type: DAEMON
Library: mysqlx.so
License: GPL
...
```

Additional info: Then installed [mysql-shell](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/) and [python-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) (for my case)

Shell and connector are required for X DevAPI (X Protocol) programming.

Answer (score 1):

Three comments:

One: Maybe you are using  'mysqlx.so; and you forgot the closing " ' "

I mean please use 'mysqlx.so' in stead of 'mysqlx.so

Two: We expect to find the file mysqlx.so in the that /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/.

Is the file mysqlx.so in than path /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/

Three: If so, maybe you have to check if the file mysqlx.so has full permissions for the user that controls mysql.

Comment: Comment One: That is typo.  Comment Two: mysqlx.so is not present in Ubuntu (but present in macos).